# ggplot dual reversed y axis and geom_hline intercept calculation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a line graph in ggplot2 with two y axes, and want only one dataset (blue) plotted on a reversed axis and want the other dataset (red) plotted on a different scale from the first. However, the code I am working with reverses both axes, and although the second y axis has been coded to have a different scale the second dataset (red) is being plotted using the scale of the first y axis. Furthermore I have created a line (green) for which I have to determine where the blue line intercepts it. I know the latter part of this question has been asked before and was answered, however it was noted in that post that the solution doesn't actually work. Any input would be helpful! Thank you! I've provided a sample dataset as mine is too large to recreate.

```
time<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
height<-c(100,330,410,570,200,270,230,390,400,420)
temp<-c(37,33,14,12,35,34,32,28,26,24)
tempdf<-data.frame(time,height,temp)

makeplot<-ggplot(tempdf,aes(x=time)) + geom_line(aes(y=height),color="Blue") 
    + geom_line(aes(y=temp),color="Red")+
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis=sec_axis(~./100,name = 
    "Temperature"),trans="reverse")+
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=250), color="green")
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you want height on a reversed axis? That would suggest it is depth.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Calculating the intersection between two lines has very little to do with the plot itself.

Comment: @neilfws yes in my real data I am working with depth, I just thought it would be easier for the example to discuss height for some reason.

Comment: @Axeman I lumped the questions together to see if there was some way to find intercepts using ggplot since the line graph itself is not a function and therefore I am unable to just plug in numbers to calculate the intercept, however if there is not way to accomplish this using ggplot I will separate the questions.

Comment: Alright. I think the intersection is better solved outside `ggplot`. The other question about axes is quite tricky, since `ggplot` doesn't properly support dual axes like you are trying to use them (only linear transformations of the same scale, such as inches and cm). This is by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative is a path plot:

```
ggplot(tempdf, aes(height, temp)) + 
  geom_path() + 
  geom_point(aes(fill = time), size = 8, shape = 21) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = time)) + 
  viridis::scale_fill_viridis()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, these are great and will definitely be helpful in my future analyses!

Answer (score 3):

ggplot will only do 1:1 axis transformations, and if it flips one axis, will flip both, so you need to figure out an equation to translate your axes. Multiplying (or dividing) by a negative flips your temperature axis back to a standard increasing scale. These two equations worked to get the sample data you had on the same scale.

```
height = temp*(-10) + 600
temp = (height - 600)/(-10)
```

Now, you can incorporate the equations into your plot code, the first to translate the temperature data into numbers that fit on the height scale, the second to translate your secondary axis numbers to a scale that shows temperature.

```
makeplot<-ggplot(tempdf,aes(x=time)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=height),color="blue") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = (temp*(-10)) + 600), color="red")+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis=sec_axis(~(.-600)/(-10),name = 
                                     "Temperature"),trans="reverse")+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=250), color="green")
makeplot
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the intersection of lines problem for now, here are a couple of alternatives to dual axes. First, facets:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
tempdf %>% 
  # convert height to depth
  mutate(height = -height) %>% 
  rename(depth = height) %>% 
  gather(key, value, -time) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(time, value)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    facet_grid(key ~ ., scales = "free_y") + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks()) +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Second, use coloured points to indicate temperature at each depth:

```
tempdf %>% 
  mutate(height = -height) %>% 
  rename(depth = height) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(time, depth)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point(aes(color = temp), size = 3) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = -250, color = "blue") +
    scale_color_gradient2(midpoint = 25, 
                          low = "blue", 
                          mid = "yellow", 
                          high = "red") + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks()) + 
    theme_dark()
```

[image]